# How to configure Google Container Registry to use my domain name?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I would like to use the Google Container Registry through my own DNS server mapping to my own domain - e.g. registry.mydomain.com. How can I accomplish this mapping?

Comment: I have a rough idea to set up HTTP reverse proxy in front of GCR that would only transform the headers, but I have not tried implementing it. Have you tried that?

Comment: Have you found any solution?